# Using while(true) in android service effect the device?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

What about if i use a while(true) to check sqlLitedatabase all time and never stop is it effect the devices or bad way or it's ok with service ?
In other way what if i do something forever at background (InService)
something like that.

```
while(true)
 {
  select from sqllitedatabase
  checkthe variables
  update it
}
```

Comment: that way you will kill your battery after minutes

Comment: Don't do that, that's terrible. Consider using a `ContentProvider` and do the stuff you want to do when actually something changes in the database.

Comment: i see that notification do something like that it wait 1 seconds then try to receive and also on ...... is it kill the battery and how can i stop this ? or it work with other way ?

Comment: I want to add data to offlinedatabase if internet is offline and when the user connect to the internet i want to send this data to my server is any good way to do this thing

Comment: I don't know why you would need a loop for that.  You can't rely on the Service for this anyway because a Service is liable to be killed off by the system whenever Android feels like it.

Comment: read [Creating a Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)